# Unable to install pyaudio on osx lion

Tags: osx-lion, pyaudio

I'd like to install pyaudio on osx lion but i'm unable to do it. Everytime i try with the pkg, it doesn't install anything. When i try to install it with pip i have the following error (among a lot of other lines) :

```
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/11/gfpzwjdd6dj7hbz7dpbvx9y40000gn/T//ccYnQM1k.out (No such file or directory)
```

error: command '/usr/bin/llvm-gcc' failed with exit status 1

If anyone can help me, thank you.

Comment: I too had similar problems. Try this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921406/mac-10-4-sdk-in-mountain-lion/12922354#12922354][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921406/mac-10-4-sdk-in-mountain-lion/12922354#12922354

Answer (score 5):

I had to manually install it to get anything working. You'll need the source distributions for both pyaudio and portaudio.

Firstly I installed portaudio with MacPorts (not from the source distribution):

```
sudo port install portaudio
```

pyaudio then refused to install as it couldn't find the pa_mac_core.h and portaudio.h headers. After copying these from the [portaudio source distribution](http://www.portaudio.com/archives/pa_stable_v19_20111121.tgz) include folder into [pyaudio's src folder](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/packages/pyaudio-0.2.4.tar.gz), I had to uncomment line 49 of pa_mac_core.h:

```
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Doing this allowed me to get pyaudio to install using a simple

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

(I probably didn't need superuser for the portaudio install, but pyaudio wouldn't install unless I did it as a superuser)

Comment: After days of futzing around with portaudio/pyaudio, this answer is what helped me out. This works in a virtualenv even when the env does not see the portaudio installation. PyAudio only needs these header files during install. I did not have to comment out `#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

Comment: This worked for me, no hacking around the pyaudio source: https://gist.github.com/jiaaro/9767512210a1d80a8a0d

Comment: same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include