# Mac 10.4 SDK in Mountain Lion

Tags: python, xcode, macos

I have Mac OS 10.8.2, Python 2.7.3, Xcode 4.5.1.

I am trying to install `portaudio` (so that I can use `import pyaudio` in `python`) following the instructions in http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_mac_coreaudio.html.

As mentioned in the site, I downloaded MacOSX10.4 SDK from http://connect.apple.com, which downloaded as DMG file. I installed it successfully. But `MacOSX10.4.sdk` never got itself placed it in the path `Applications/Xcode.app/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/SDKs`, along with `MacOSX10.7.sdk` and `MacOS10.8.sdk`. Considering its unavailability, `./configure && make` shows error.

Here is a screenshot of the folder
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the errors [image]

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just install it using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). I am running MountainLion and it installed in 14 seconds.

```
$ brew install portaudio
==> Downloading http://www.portaudio.com/archives/pa_stable_v19_20111121.tgz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading patches
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching patching file include/pa_mac_core.h
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.20111121 --enable-mac-universal=no
==> make install /usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.20111121: 8 files, 308K, built in 14 seconds
```

Comment: Yeah, homebrew is very useful and quite easy to set up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did exactly like you asked. The results are exactly what u showed. But while trying to `import pyaudio` in python, I still get `Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first`. How do I resolve it?

Comment: This is the output `>>> import pyaudio
Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first.` Tryin to `import _portaudio`, I get 
`ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_portaudio.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_portaudio.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper`

Comment: It could be that pyaudio installed incorrectly. I would try reinstalling it. I just did a `sudo easy_install pyaudio` and after installing I can import `pyaudio` without errors. `sudo pip install pyaudio` worked as well. I couldn't get it to install without using `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. I did `sudo easy_install pyaudio` but still remains the same

Comment: Did you try uninstalling it first with something like `sudo pip uninstall pyaudio`?