# How do I install PyAudio in virtualenv on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, pyaudio

I have tried

```
easy_install pyaudio
```

and it doesn't work.  I get the following:

```
Searching for pyaudio
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyaudio/
Reading http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/
Best match: pyaudio 0.2.7
Downloading http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/packages/pyaudio-0.2.7.tar.gz
Processing pyaudio-0.2.7.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/vg/98k5hfl52m16wm45ckdx1_5c0000gp/T/easy_install-s1wLkT/PyAudio-0.2.7/setup.cfg
Running PyAudio-0.2.7/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/vg/98k5hfl52m16wm45ckdx1_5c0000gp/T/easy_install-s1wLkT/PyAudio-0.2.7/egg-dist-tmp-pFDrFR
warning: no files found matching '*.c' under directory 'test'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
#include "portaudio.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that you have not installed Portaudio.
You can get it from Macports or Homebrew.

- `sudo port install portaudio`
- `sudo brew install portaudio`

Comment: Will this work with virtualenv?  I would have thought it would be out of the python path Edit: sorry had a dumb moment!

Comment: Or with homebrew: `brew install portaudio`

Comment: If you're in a virtualenv (or using virtualenvwrapper), pyaudio will not find portaudio during install. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10290595/1386245) helped me out tremendously.

Comment: This answer was the easiest for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include

Answer (score 7):

Or with brew

```
brew install portaudio
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably dependent on some C library which needs to be compiled and installed separately. Like whatever provides 'portaudio.h'.  Most of these things are tested on `linux` which has package managers that can take care of this sort of thing automagically whereas OS X is non-free and has to circumnavigate licensing minefields.