# when installing pyaudio, pip cannot find portaudio.h in /usr/local/include

Tags: python, macos, pyaudio

I'm using mac osx 10.10
As the PyAudio Homepage said, I install the PyAudio using

```
brew install portaudio 
pip install pyaudio
```

the installation of portaudio seems successful, I can find headers and libs in /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib
but when I try to install pyaudio, it gives me an error that

```
src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
#include "portaudio.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

actually it is in /usr/local/include
why can't it find the file?
some answers to similar questions are not working for me(like using virtualenv, or compile it manually), and I want to find a simple way to solve this.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Since `pyAudio` has `portAudio` as a dependency, you first have to install portaudio.

```
#for Mac
brew install portaudio
```

Then try: `pip install pyAudio`. If the problem persists after installing `portAudio`, you can specify the directory path where the compiler will be able to find the source programs (e.g: `portaudio.h`). Since the headers should be in the `/usr/local/include` directory:

```
pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio
```

Comment: The version of PyAudio was 0.2.9.

Comment: This seems to work, but why? Shouldn't /usr/local directories be the default? build_ext seems to run (and fail to find things) by default.

Comment: It works for me too. It seems you specified the paths to look for headers manually, is there any way to configure it as default?

Comment: this worked for me, but I had to use sudo on my machine (El Capitan, upgraded from Yosemite)

Comment: I had to use sudo on the pip install command to get it to finally install.

Comment: For anyone using macports, /opt/local/include and /opt/local/lib worked for me

Comment: Thanks man, that helped. (we have to explicitly add the user's local lib and includes)

Comment: To get the explicit path to portaudio's header files, use `brew info portaudio`.

Comment: Here's a bit more robust snippet for those who have a non-default homebrew dir, `pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option="-I$(brew --prefix)/include" --global-option="-L$(brew --prefix)/lib" pyaudio`

Comment: Neither this nor @mathandy's command worked for me... I still get 
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: For me this worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73338550/1822138

Comment: None of the suggestions have worked for me. I've tried everything in all responses and it can't find my `portaudio.h` which is definitely there. Super weird!

Answer (score 30):

On Ubuntu builds:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

For Python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio
```

Answer (score 24):

I needed to do the following to install PortAudio on Debian

```
sudo apt install portaudio19-dev
```

I also `apt install`'d  `python3-portaudio` before that, although it didn't work. I'm not sure if that contributed as well.

Comment: it actually worked after installing `portaudio19-dev`. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 10

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22

Comment: Also worked for me on Ubuntu22

Comment: worked on me on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: this should be the answer!!

Comment: worked for me on debian 12

Answer (score 16):

You have to install portaudio first then link that file. Only then you can find that header file (i.e, portaudio.h). To install portaudio in mac by using `HomeBrew` program use following commands.

```
brew install portaudio
brew link portaudio
pip install pyaudio
```

sudo is not needed if you're admin. We should refrain using sudo as it messes up lots of permissions.

Comment: This actually worked for me. Didn't need to link, however.

Comment: i'm on OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.5 and this worked for me as well

Answer (score 14):

First, you can use Homebrew to install portaudio.

```
brew install portaudio
```

Then try to find the portaudio path:

```
sudo find / -name "portaudio.h"
```

In my case it is at `/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.6.0/include` .

Run the command below to install pyaudio

```
pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.6.0/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.6.0/lib' pyaudio
```

Comment: Instead of `sudo find`, you can also get the path to `portaudio/x.x.x/include` using `brew info portaudio`, which should print out a path like `/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0`. Then it's just a matter of adding `/include`.

Comment: In my case, I was trying to install `neopixel`, which required `pyaudio`, which needed `portaudio.h`. Simply doing `brew install portaudio` was enough to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

On Raspbian:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

Comment: On raspbian with python-env or conda envs: `sudo apt install portaudio19-dev & pip install pyaudio`

Answer (score 8):

on Centos:

```
yum install -y portaudio portaudio-devel && pip install pyaudio
```

Comment: No package `portaudio` available and `portaudio-devel`

Answer (score 8):

Just for the record for folks using MacPorts and not Homebrew:

```
$ [sudo] port install portaudio
$ pip install pyaudio --global-option="build_ext"  --global-option="-I/opt/local/include" --global-option="-L/opt/local/lib"
```

Comment: `$(brew --prefix)` won't work for those without Homebrew. This answer was specifically for those using MacPorts and not Homebrew.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a bit of robustness (in case of a non-default homebrew dir) to the snippet from @fukudama,

```
brew install portaudio
pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option="-I$(brew --prefix)/include" --global-option="-L$(brew --prefix)/lib" pyaudio
```

Answer (score 4):

For me on 10.10.5 the paths were under `/opt/local`. I had to add `/opt/local/bin` to my `/etc/paths` file. And the command line that worked was

```
sudo pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/local/include' --global-option='-L/opt/local/lib' pyaudio
```

Answer (score 3):

this is the tested answer for MacBook Pro m2 chip:

first find the location of the `portaudio.h` file by

```
sudo find / -name "portaudio.h"
```

then, once you find the location, copy it and use it in this command.

```
LDFLAGS="-L/{opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/}lib" CFLAGS="-I/{opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0}/include" pip3 install pyaudio
```

Here replace the location from { } into you file location hopefully this works. I have tried above solutions and this one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using anaconda/miniconda to manage your python environments then

`conda install pyaudio`

installs `portaudio` at the same time as `pyaudio`

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  portaudio          pkgs/main/osx-64::portaudio-19.6.0-h647c56a_4
  pyaudio            pkgs/main/osx-64::pyaudio-0.2.11-py37h1de35cc_2
```

Answer (score 1):

***On [Termux](https://termux.com/)** (this is what worked for me):*

1. `pkg install python`
2. `bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://its-pointless.github.io/setup-pointless-repo.sh)"`
3. `pkg install portaudio`
4. `pip install pyaudio`

**Source:** [*pyaudio installing #6235*](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/6235)

Comment: correct: pkg install portaudio ... not portudio (can't edit)

Answer (score 1):

For M1 mac, this is worked for me:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib" CFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include" pip3 install pyaudio
```

Res:

```
 Created wheel for pyaudio: filename=PyAudio-0.2.12-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl size=24170 sha256=c74eb581e6bca2400f681f68d33654002722969f1a455ffce87e4e5da05471d8
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/m_/kzyr4q_11cl35ngrj77k28f00000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-ql1x8ums/wheels/93/08/0b/b915ab1895927641737175e5bc7b6111e8ed0c26daabeecba0
Successfully built pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
Successfully installed pyaudio-0.2.12
```

Be noted, **do not using find /** its very slow and stupid, using brew info portaudio

Answer (score 0):

To install on OpenSuse:

```
 sudo zypper in portaudio
 sudo zypper in portaudio-devel
 sudo zypper in python311-PyAudio
```

Do replace "*python311*" with the python version you're aiming for

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this question and answers when trying to install/build `pyaudio` package on Macos Sonoma 14.

Original problem was also `portaudio.h` header not being found. Solved it by installing `portaudio` using MacPorts:

```
$ sudo port install portaudio
```

After that, I tried to install the python package `pyaudio` and was getting errors like:

```
$ LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib" CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include" pip install pyaudio
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/Headers/MIDIServices.h:1968:65: error: unknown type name 'MIDIReadBlock'; did you mean 'MIDIReadProc'?
       1968 |                                                                 MIDIReadBlock           readBlock )
            |                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
            |                                                                 MIDIReadProc
      error: command '/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-12' failed with exit code 1
```

Solved the problem by unsetting `$CC` and `$CXX` env variables which were pointing to my GCC12 compiler. This effectively enabled Apple's XCode compiler. Hope this helps somebody else with a similar problem.