# speech recognition in PyCharm on Mac missing PyAudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

```
#raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
```

# AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

# I have tried every type of pip or sudo type of commands but its
    # not working it just says PyAudio is missing

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# get audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak:")
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: e__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/bd/tl0f7qxn4hg1btz77np_5qsr0000gn/T/pip-record-_r14muyy/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/lokeshv/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/include/site/python3.7/pyaudio" failed

Comment: Perhaps try the steps from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851379/pyaudio-installation-on-mac-python-3

Answer (score 3):

You may need to get some additional packages, based off of operating system.

## Debian Linux

If you don't have Homebrew (brew), download the it [here](https://brew.sh/).

```
$ brew install portaudio
$ pip install pyaudio
```

## MacOS

If you don't have Homebrew (brew), download the it [here](https://brew.sh/).

```
$ brew install portaudio
$ pip install pyaudio
```

## Windows

```
$ pip install pyaudio
```

I found this answer [here](https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/#installing-pyaudio).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly install the PyAudio Wheel from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

For more info on using speech recognition with python you can check out [this](https://www.codinground.com/speech-recognition/)