# No available formula or cask with the name "portaudio"

Tags: homebrew, pyaudio, portaudio

I have installed homebrew.

I was trying install PyAudio but to install PyAudio I had to install portaudio .
I wrote " brew install portaudio " in terminal and I got many errors.

Error: No available formula or cask with the name "portaudio".

fatal: Needed a single revision
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "portaudio".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

After this I tried " pip install pyaudio " and got more errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b9AA.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyaudio installation on mac (python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851379/pyaudio-installation-on-mac-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

i got those exact errors and solved it after following these steps:

1. uninstall homebrew `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`
2. re-install homebrew
   `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
3. `brew install portaudio`
4. `pip install pyaudio`