# Unable to Install PyAudio on Mac

Tags: python

I am trying to installing PyAudio on mac using the following commands:-

```
brew install portaudio

pip install pyaudio
```

I have already installed brew (as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48572091/13218692)

Is there any way to install PyAudio on Mac wothout installing Xcode as it is a 17GB File? Appreciate yuor help guys!!

[image]

Comment: What happened with this commands?

Comment: @Trilarion I have attached the image of the error I am getting in the terminal

Comment: The xcode-select thing that it's talking about won't be 17GB I'm pretty sure. Xcode should only be that size if you're actually using xcode, and maybe have some iphone simulators in Xcode or something
Also next time can you copy and paste the error text instead of posting a photo? Thanks

Comment: @Sam So, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Do the xcode-select thing the error mentions, if you have to install all of xcode, and it's taking up a lot of space, you should be able to use the terminal and run this command `du -h /Applications/Xcode.app  | awk '$1 ~ /G/' | sort -g` to find out what is taking up the most space in there and there's lot's of stuff you can remove like `iOS.simruntime`. The `awk '$1 ~ /G/'` will give you everything over 1GB, use`/M/` for everything greater than 1MB but less than 1GB

Answer (score 0):

The solution to install PyAudio on Mac without downloading Xcode is simply type in the following statement in the Terminal:-

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

And, then type in:-

```
pip install pyaudio
```

That's it!! Now, PyAudio is successfully installed on your Mac.