# PyAudio does not install on OS X Big Sur

Tags: python, pyaudio

After entering command `pip install PyAudio` installing started, and then it gave me an error

```
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I can't understand what is it.  At first I noticed that `pip` is not at the latest version. I still have the same problem after upgrading and it still can't be installed. I am using PyCharm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851379/how-to-install-pyaudio-on-mac-using-python-3 This should help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install pyaudio on mac using Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851379/how-to-install-pyaudio-on-mac-using-python-3)