# PyAudio (MacOS, M1) - ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1, pyaudio

Help me install the PyAudio library on MacOS (M1), I tried everything :(

---

My actions

1. brew remove portaudio
2. brew install portaudio
3. pip3 install pyaudio

---

brew reinstall portaudio

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/portaudio/manifests/19.7.0-1
Already downloaded: /Users/code232/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/2ba32ec74d5080567eae3412994e5c8bc39afcd1dacfe3a0d347d210e47c5f7e--portaudio-19.7.0-1.bottle_manifest.json

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/portaudio/blobs/sha256:8f390b
Already downloaded: /Users/code232/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c1fa92f01d5c060c79bea1c294e230dc5a074a49c42f39b9bf68bffa6c79ea98--portaudio--19.7.0.arm64_monterey.bottle.1.tar.gz

==> Reinstalling portaudio

==> Pouring portaudio--19.7.0.arm64_monterey.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0: 33 files, 543.2KB

==> Running `brew cleanup portaudio`...

Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).

---

```
        pip install pyaudio      
            Collecting pyaudio
              Using cached PyAudio-0.2.12.tar.gz (42 kB)
              Installing build dependencies ... done
              Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
              Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
            Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
              Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
              error: subprocess-exited-with-error
              
              × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
              │ exit code: 1
              ╰─> [16 lines of output]
                  running bdist_wheel
                  running build
                  running build_py
                  creating build
                  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
                  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
                  running build_ext
                  building '_portaudio' extension
                  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
                  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src
                  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src/_portaudiomodule.o
                  src/_portaudiomodule.c:31:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
                  #include "portaudio.h"
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  1 error generated.
                  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
                  [end of output]
              
            note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
            ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
            Failed to build pyaudio
            ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to install pyaudio on mac using Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851379/how-to-install-pyaudio-on-mac-using-python-3)

First install Xcode. Then restart your computer. Afterwards run the commands in sequence,

```
xcode-select --install
brew remove portaudio
brew install portaudio
pip3 install pyaudio
```

Comment: 1. xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates; 2. Uninstalling /opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0... (33 files, 543.2KB); 3. Running `brew cleanup portaudio`; 4. ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects