# portaudio.h not found when installing pyaudio in Mac

Tags: python, macos, pyaudio, portaudio

I created a virtual environment like this

```
mkdir ai
cd ai
```

```
conda create --prefix ./env python=3.8
conda activate ./env
```

and installed libraries

```
brew install portaudio
pip install pyaudio
```

but an error was thrown

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.12.tar.gz (42 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310
      copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/premkumarsinha/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/premkumarsinha/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -DMACOSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/Users/premkumarsinha/miniforge3/include/python3.10 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-310/src/_portaudiomodule.o
      src/_portaudiomodule.c:31:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
      #include "portaudio.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
```

So I ran this

```
brew find portaudio
```

and I got the dir for it;

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0
```

than I ran this command

```
pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib' pyaudio
```

But still I am getting the same error what should I do.

Comment: Check your pip version try to upgrade your pip & setuptool

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Its already upgraded.

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33851618/14457833) this may help you