# Recording sound using python language

Tags: python

I want to create an audio microphone recorder in Python but I don't know how to do it. Will I need a library. Which one ?
I am on a Mac (OS X 10.11)

Answer (score 0):

Python-sounddevice looks good :

http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.3/

you have a bunch of parameters to control duration and/or wait... See the doc. 
I'm testing it right now.

Edit : For your installation problem if you're using pyaudio, see [when installing pyaudio, pip cannot find portaudio.h in /usr/local/include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include)