# ICan't Do Anything With Pip because it won't install anything

Tags: python, windows, pip

Any time i try to install anything with pip i would get this type of error. I've updated my computer, updated visual studios, pip 20.0.2, python 3.8.2, and still nothing works, I've even tried reinstalling everything.

ERROR: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Yqv.png

Comment: Did you try running the pip install from the command line and not visual studio?

Comment: duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include

Comment: It's not a duplicate because that issue was on OSX with brew, and this person is on Windows and is not using brew.

Comment: Jortega, I have tried it from visual studios, cmd, and the pycharm terminals.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python package installation issues: PyAudio, PortAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio)

Comment: @tedivm Fear not, there is a QA for Windows, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992375/python-package-installation-issues-pyaudio-portaudio

Comment: i had to share it as a question because no matter how i formatted it 'stack overflow' didn't like it and i couldn't send this question.

Comment: @Chris, download and install the `whl` file. Simply download `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) and then do `pip install path/to/PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) on your system to use one of the libraries you're trying to install.

Answer (score -1):

try using `pip3` instead of `pip` or check paths

Comment: im not familiar with python, how would i check paths?

Comment: http://www.portaudio.com/download.html try installing PortAudio first

Comment: for vs code you can try http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows.html