# PyAudio installation always fails on Mac

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

Firstly, I tried

```
pip install pyaudio
```

But that didn't work... I found that I need PortAudio, so installed it with `brew`:

```
brew install portaudio
```

That worked and then I restarted my Mac.

But `pip install pyaudio` still doesn't work and I get the below error message:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -u -c
> 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/private/var/folders/12/44t6pktj77xbqmyp7x368tdr0000gn/T/pip-install-gvxfbjmp/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/12/44t6pktj77xbqmyp7x368tdr0000gn/T/pip-install-gvxfbjmp/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d
> /private/var/folders/12/44t6pktj77xbqmyp7x368tdr0000gn/T/pip-wheel-gvmpobvy
> cwd: /private/var/folders/12/44t6pktj77xbqmyp7x368tdr0000gn/T/pip-install-gvxfbjmp/pyaudio/
> Complete output (16 lines):
> running bdist_wheel
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
> copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
> running build_ext
> building '_portaudio' extension
> creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
> creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src
> xcrun -sdk macosx clang -arch x86_64 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders
> -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Headers
> -DMACOSX=1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m
> -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
> src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
> #include "portaudio.h"
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
> ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio

I also tried `pip3 install pyaudio` without any luck.

BTW I am just doing this because I want to use the Python Speech Recognition API and I think `pyaudio` is necessary... is it?

Comment: Have you tried this specific answer already? `pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very likely you need to specify the directory path where the compiler can find the source programs like `portaudio.h`.

Under assumption that the headers are in `/usr/local/include` directory, try to run the below command in the Terminal:

```
pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that with the Xcode command-line. Reinstall using this

```
xcode-select --install
```

after xcode is fixed the command('xcrun') should be able to run so just reuse

```
pip3 install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to upgrade pip
`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

-- Successfully installed pip-21.2.4

and/or invoke pip3
`pip3 install ...`