# How to fix "Command errored out with exit status 1:" in PyCharm for pip install PyAudio==0.2.10

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pyaudio, portaudio

I am simply trying to download the python library PyAudio, however an error occurs with this description:

```
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for PyAudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio: started
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/ricochetnkweso/PycharmProjects/MyProject/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-install-5h_j3ka6/pyaudio_f4e97b082e5f4b3887e8cee9db3638ab/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-install-5h_j3ka6/pyaudio_f4e97b082e5f4b3887e8cee9db3638ab/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-record-nw3a63yb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/ricochetnkweso/PycharmProjects/MyProject/venv/include/site/python3.7/PyAudio
         cwd: /private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-install-5h_j3ka6/pyaudio_f4e97b082e5f4b3887e8cee9db3638ab/
    Complete output (18 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
    
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/Users/ricochetnkweso/PycharmProjects/MyProject/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
    #include "portaudio.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/ricochetnkweso/PycharmProjects/MyProject/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-install-5h_j3ka6/pyaudio_f4e97b082e5f4b3887e8cee9db3638ab/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-install-5h_j3ka6/pyaudio_f4e97b082e5f4b3887e8cee9db3638ab/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-record-nw3a63yb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/ricochetnkweso/PycharmProjects/MyProject/venv/include/site/python3.7/PyAudio Check the logs for full command output.
```

Could someone please explain this very easily as I am a novice programmer. I'm not really sure what's going on here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+%27portaudio.h%27+file+not+found

Comment: Try [`brew install portaudio`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62751582/7976758)