# Installing PyAudio gives error "portaudio.h" file not found

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio, portaudio

I have been trying to install PyAudio for a project. I am working on a Mac with the M1 Chip, on OS 11.0.1.

Every time I run `pip3 install pyaudio` I get the same error:

```
    #include "portaudio.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I have installed portaudio through `brew install portaudio` and have x-code command line tools but it still doesn't work. I have also tried putting sudo in front of it but no luck.

Any help is appreciated!

Here's an image of the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULtL6.png)

Answer (score 7):

The PortAudio header file can't be located.

Try running `brew link` before installing PyAudio:

```sh
brew install portaudio
brew link portaudio
pip3 install pyaudio
```

If this does not work then locate the file, `sudo find / -name "portaudio.h"`, and supply the path as a `build_ext` option through the `pip3 install` command. In my case the path returned is `/usr/local/include/portaudio.h`. Hence, the command is as follows:

```sh
pip3 install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio
```

These possible solutions are all described in the related question:
[when installing pyaudio, pip cannot find portaudio.h in /usr/local/include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include)

Comment: Thanks this works on 2021 Mac Mini M1, installing in python3.6 venv