# pip install pyaudio gcc error "function declaration isn’t a prototype"

Tags: python, gcc, macos-catalina, pyaudio

`pip install pyaudio` failed on MacOS with error `src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory #include <stdio.h>`

After doing some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include) I ran the following commands:

1/ `export CPATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/`

2/ `pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio`

But got errors `/usr/local/include/portaudio.h:114:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]` and  `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1` instead.

It seems upgrading to MacOS Catalina messed up my Xcode Developer Tools C headers but am not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve this by copying portaudio.h from /usr/local/include/ to anaconda3/include.