# How can I install pyaudio on a mac?

Tags: python, macos, pyaudio

I am trying to install pyaudio on a Mac.

Here is what I have done:

- Installed python 3.9.7
- Installed homebrew
- Removed portaudio (brew remove portaudio)
- Installed portaudio (brew install portaudio)

Now I am trying to install pyaudio:

`python3 -m pip install pyaudio`
(same result for `pip3 install pyaudio`)

This is the error message that I get:

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hc/z83533l573lc7bbdnfqd7jzw0000gn/T/pip-install-ukm0_nma/pyaudio_11253f82c20448a3a6ab37fa24ca3049/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hc/z83533l573lc7bbdnfqd7jzw0000gn/T/pip-install-ukm0_nma/pyaudio_11253f82c20448a3a6ab37fa24ca3049/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/hc/z83533l573lc7bbdnfqd7jzw0000gn/T/pip-record-giib8e7d/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyaudio
         cwd: /private/var/folders/hc/z83533l573lc7bbdnfqd7jzw0000gn/T/pip-install-ukm0_nma/pyaudio_11253f82c20448a3a6ab37fa24ca3049/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
    #include "portaudio.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/hc/z83533l573lc7bbdnfqd7jzw0000gn/T/pip-install-ukm0_nma/pyaudio_11253f82c20448a3a6ab37fa24ca3049/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/hc/z83533l573lc7bbdnfqd7jzw0000gn/T/pip-install-ukm0_nma/pyaudio_11253f82c20448a3a6ab37fa24ca3049/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/hc/z83533l573lc7bbdnfqd7jzw0000gn/T/pip-record-giib8e7d/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyaudio Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

What can I do?

I have tried the various suggestions in the search engines and YouTube.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when installing pyaudio, pip cannot find portaudio.h in /usr/local/include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include)

Comment: Thanks, but no it does not solve the problem.  The file "portaudio.h" is not downloaded (cannot find searching "This Mac") and I **think** this is why the install terminates.  I tried all the options given: Homebrew is installed (OK), Portaudio is installed (OK), xcode is installed (OK).  Yet PyAudio fails.

Comment: Are you sure that `brew install portaudio` was successful? Doing `brew info portaudio` should tell you where it's installed (it should show a path like /usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/..), which should have the include/portaudio.h file. Then you can explicitly tell pip the path to the include folder.

Comment: (base) frederik@Frederiks-MacBook-Air ~ % ```brew info portaudio```

portaudio: stable 19.7.0 (bottled), 
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0 (33 files, 560KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-09-15 at 09:52:43
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/portaudio.rb

==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
 Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 8,062 (30 days), 24,508 (90 days), 99,287 (365 days)
install-on-request: 3,515 (30 days), 10,571 (90 days), 44,494 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)

What do I need to do now?  Thanks...

Comment: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include` _should_ have portaudio.h. Then you can try [one of the answers from the link I shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33821084/2745495), where you _explicitly_ tell pip where to find portaudio.h (by giving the path to the `/include` directory). It seems your Homebrew installs stuff on a non-regular dir. Normally it's on `/usr/local/`.

Answer (score 0):

Download Pyaudio and install it manually

[Download Link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

[Another guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjqy6KJw_7yAhWgCjQIHXF2BtMQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcs.gmu.edu%2F%7Emarks%2F112%2Fprojects%2FPlaySong.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0MWI-yhUY2s1YNOsCG32L5)

Homebrew and building PyAudio also requires installing the Command Line Tools for Xcode

[Linux guide](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)

You can use the Linux guide to install it on your mac

There are other ways too:
Use Anaconda: Install anaconda and use its package manager and other abilities.
Use Virtual Envs: Install Pyenv

Comment: Thanks, but the download link you included (https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) is for Windows only.  Does this exist for a Mac also?

Comment: I don't know if it exists for Mac, But you can try to install it on Mac, it is a Wheel file!!.