# I tried everything to install pyaudio on macOS Monterrey

Tags: python, macos, pyaudio

1. I installed brew
2. Use brew install portaudio
3. I link with brew link portaudio
4. Installed pyaudio with pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib' pyaudio

and I tried install with pip install pyaudio and pip3 install pyaudio

But unhappily I always have the same error

```
    Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.12.tar.gz (42 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
      AssertionError:
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-310
      copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-310
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-310/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk -DMACOSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I</opt/homebrew/opt/portaudi>include/ -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-310/src/_portaudiomodule.o
      src/_portaudiomodule.c:31:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
      #include "portaudio.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Have you tried installing `portaudio` using homebrew? `brew install portaudio`?

Comment: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

Comment: Yes, I installed using brew

Comment: Did you find this SO answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include

Comment: Yes, I tried....

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as well, but following work-around worked for me.

1. Install portaudio
   `brew install portaudio`
2. Link
   `brew link portaudio`
3. Locate the library and includes
   `sudo find / -name "portaudio.h"`
4. Use it with global options
   `pip3 install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include/' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib/' pyaudio`

But this fails as you are pointing above. For some reason, it doesn't include the path for libs and include with `build_ext` option.

```
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.12.tar.gz (42 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 42.9/42.9 kB 1.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-39
      copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-39
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-39/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/koteshk/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/koteshk/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -DMACOSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/Users/koteshk/miniforge3/include/python3.9 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-cpython-39/src/_portaudiomodule.o
      src/_portaudiomodule.c:31:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
      #include "portaudio.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
```

5. Work around
   Manually copy the libs and include files to one of the system paths. Note you may have to create the directory if it's not present.
   `sudo cp -r /opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include/* /usr/local/include` 
   `sudo cp -r /opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib/* /usr/local/lib`
6. Install pyaudio
   `pip install pyaudio`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved my own problem. To solved this problem portaudio.h just follow the topics bellow.

### Pyaudio for MACOS users --> Project with Speech Recognition

1. Install homebrew --> https://brew.sh/index_pt-br
2. `brew install portaudio`
3. `brew link portaudio`
4. type `LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix portaudio)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix portaudio)/include" pip install pyaudio`
5. `brew install flac` --> https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/flac
6. install speech_recognition with pip