# Can't install pyaudio on python 3.8.10

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-3.8, pyaudio

I'm on windows 10 wsl2, python 3.8.10, and I tried installing pyaudio and portaudio via pip and pipwin3, which didn't work. Then I installed portaudio from the website. After I [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513522/when-installing-pyaudio-pip-cannot-find-portaudio-h-in-usr-local-include). I used this instead though since portaudio was in my working directory:
`pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/portaudio/include' --global-option='-L/baili/local/lib' pyaudio`

Got this error now:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Implying --no-binary=:all: due to the presence of --build-option / --global-option / --install-option. Consider using --config-settings for more flexibility.
DEPRECATION: --no-binary currently disables reading from the cache of locally built wheels. In the future --no-binary will not influence the wheel cache. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use the --no-cache-dir option. You can use the flag --use-feature=no-binary-enable-wheel-cache to test the upcoming behaviour. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11453
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.12.tar.gz (42 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  WARNING: Ignoring --global-option when building pyaudio using PEP 517
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/_portaudiomodule.o
      src/_portaudiomodule.c:31:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
         31 | #include "portaudio.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm lost right now, if you have a link to the pyaudio file it'd be cool, or a fix to this thanks

pipwin, pip, pip3, website

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to be quite simple:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyaudio
```

this also made me realize that I forgot to put conda in my sys environment variables :P